user.uid showing null but defined
I'm making a type of blog websites where only admins can post. So I decided to make an Admin Navbar and I'm validating if the user is admin or not from the database in Firebase. I want to store all the user's data into a state but when I'm trying to get the document by using the user's uid, I'm getting an error:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Here is my code:
AdminNav.jsx:
const AdminNav = ({ user }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const id = auth.currentUser.uid;
  console.log(id); // Returning uid correctly
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(id) // Causing the problem
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          setUserData((prev) => {
            return [...prev, doc.data()];
          });
        });
      });
    console.log(id); // Returning uid correctly
  }, []);
  if (user) {
    if (user.uid === userData[0].uid) {
      return <AdminNavbar />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
};

I tried to log the user uid in the console that is working fine but when i try to get the document, its creating a problem
Edit: The problem is solved now!
I read the Firebase Docs carefully and found out that I wasn't supposed to map the data that I got. I have changed the code to like this and it is working:
const AdminNav = ({ user }) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const id = auth.currentUser.uid;
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        setUserData(doc.data())
      });
  }, []);
  if (user) {
    if (user.uid === userData.uid) {
      return <AdminNavbar />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
};


The first time this component renders, before the database query completes, userData is assigned an initial value of an empty array, which means userData[0] is undefined.  The error happens when you then use userData[0].uid to read the uid property from that undefined value.
You should probably check that userData[0] has an expected value before using it like this.
  if (user && userData[0] !== undefined) {
    if (user.uid === userData[0].uid) {


sir, this is not the one thats causing the problem. In console, its showing that the problem is from line 7 in which im assining the "id" variable, but i think the problem is from where im fetching the document using the user's id (which i have mentioned)

You should edit the question to explain in more detail what the problem is.  Don't leave important debugging information like this in comments - everything we need should be in the question itself.
